# Compute shortest distance from a given vertex to a vertex with a defined property

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm, gremlin, gremlin-server

A well understood problem in graph theory is to compute the shortest distance between two vertices.

What I want to do is find the shortest distance from a given vertex to the *closest* vertex which has a certain property-value (the exact vertex that this is, is unknown).

For example, find the shortest distance from `V(1)` to the closest vertex `V(?)` where `V(?).property(color)==red`.

An approach I've used for this before is to iteratively step outwards from a focal vertex, asking each unseen neighbor along the way whether it has that `color=red`.

I also upper bounded the number of outward steps for some added efficiency, i.e. limiting the search to the *k step neighbourhood*.

1. Is there a better way to solve this problem?
2. How might one code this using **Gremlin**? (I code primarily in Python and am unsure how to migrate the algorithm across)

Comment: Chances are this is not an under-theorized problem, and just that I havn't Googled well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said this is a well known problem in graph theory, and there are many algorithms, like: Dijkstra's, that solved this problem. you can read about them [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem).

Also you can find many gremlin recipes [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.1-SNAPSHOT/recipes/), including a simple shortest path algorithm.

By changing the loop stop condition, I believe it will give you the desired result:

```
g.V(1).repeat(out().simplePath()).until(has('color', 'red')).path().limit(1)
```

Comment: This is really nice and elegant, thanks! As an extension, is there a way to traverse both outward and inward edges? (i.e. to assume that the graph is undirected when running this query)

Comment: Thanks noam I appreciate the help here

Comment: note also `shortestPath()` step in newer versions of Gremlin: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#shortestpath-step

Comment: Sorry to bother, but final question: do you know how I might modify the query above for passing *multiple* vertices? For example, `g.V()`, instead of say `g.V(1)`. I could simply take the limit statement out, but then it would compute multiple paths for the same focal vertex. Ideally I'd want to limit to 1, but *for each* vertex in `g.V()`.